# how to identify Pending Intent has been launch through NotificationService?

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I wrote an [**long live Service**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)...which actually lauch Notification Panel. I create Pending Intent to launch Activity element of same app.

So here is there any way to identify pending intent launch event?

Comment: Sorry, don't really understand your question. What do you mean by "any way to identify pending intent launch event"? Can you post some code and indicate where you are having trouble?

Comment: i need onClick kind of event when click on panel to launch intent action...got?

Comment: You are passing an `Intent` to the `NotificationManager` which is put in the `Notification`. When the user clicks on the notification, this `Intent` will be launched. As Toon Borders said in his answer you can add some "extra" to that `Intent` so that you can tell that it came from a notification. If this isn't clear, please post the code you are using to create the `Notification` and we can help you there.

Comment: @DavidWasser..yes same will work for me...but I need event notification from where I launched it...in my case it's BG service....any suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. Please explain what you mean by "event notification from where I launched it". This makes no sense :-(

Answer (score 0):

Put something in the extras of the intent that you're passing to the [`getActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) method when you're creating your `PendingIntent`. Then, in the `onCreate` method of the activity you're opening, check if that field has been set in the extras.

Comment: Thanks but sorry I forgot to mention...this is something I need in Service where I wrote code to launch Notification Panel.

Comment: Any idea/suggestion here?